# How to bind mouse click to ContentPresenter within a HierarchicalDataTemplate to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following DataTemplate used in a TreeView.

How do I have LeftMouseClick on the ContentPresenter to bind to a property of the DataType in MVVM fashion?

Thanks for any help (or better idea).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="sharedTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox
                    Focusable="False" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                />
                <ContentPresenter 
                    Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    Margin="2,0"
                />
            </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>


   <TreeView 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ReportTree}"  >

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type r:ReportViewModel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                >

                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource sharedTemplate}" />

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    ................
```

Addendum: This works!

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type r:PrinterViewModel}">
                    <!--Bind the ContentControl to the DataType-->
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
                                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource sharedTemplate}" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <h:EventToCommand                                    
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Addendum: As it turns out, the above Interaction.Trigger does work to correctly send the selected viewmodel back to the DataContext of the TreeView.   Problem solved.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Bind it to `ICommand` property of view model behind tree node? Make `ContentPresenter` clickable as part of `CheckBox`?

Comment: @dkozl I would like to click on the content and have it set a "selected Item" property in the viewmodel so that the viewmodel could delete this node from the treeview. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment clicking on `ContentPresenter` selects `TreeViewItem` but it does not toggle `CheckBox`. You don't see this behaviour or you would like that it ticks/unticks the `CheckBox`?

Comment: @dkozl I do not wish it to toggle the checkbox.

Comment: So then do you want to bind `TreeViewItem` selected state to some property of view model behind that `TreeViewItem`? Basically how do you define _"selected Item" property_?

Comment: @dkozl public object SelectedItem { get; set; }

Comment: @dkozl There will be a separate button on the view to delete the node. I am trying to allow selection of the node by mouse click. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65013/discussion-between-alan-wayne-and-dkozl).